# What is the output expected from Frog River 1problem?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

What is the output expected from the problem? If the goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river How the answer for given sample comes out to be 6???

> A small frog wants to get to the other side of a river. The frog is
>   initially located on one bank of the river (position 0) and wants to
>   get to the opposite bank (position X+1). Leaves fall from a tree onto
>   the surface of the river.
>
> You are given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers
>   representing the falling leaves. A[K] represents the position where
>   one leaf falls at time K, measured in seconds.
>
> The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the
>   other side of the river. The frog can cross only when leaves appear at
>   every position across the river from 1 to X (that is, we want to find
>   the earliest moment when all the positions from 1 to X are covered by
>   leaves). You may assume that the speed of the current in the river is
>   negligibly small, i.e. the leaves do not change their positions once
>   they fall in the river.
>
> For example, you are given integer X = 5 and array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 1   A[1] = 3   A[2] = 1   A[3] = 4   A[4] = 2   A[5] = 3
>   A[6] = 5   A[7] = 4 In second 6, a leaf falls into position 5. This is
>   the earliest time when leaves appear in every position across the
>   river.

**Time needed to reach the other end of river**

or

**The index in the array where the X is located**

or

**The index which contains the highest number?**

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.  Specifically, the question must be self-contained; no external links for the central problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cross the river, the frog needs to have leaves in all positions 1 through X (5).  The river is initially empty; one leaf per second falls into the river, at the location indicated by `A[K]`, where `K` is the time-tick at which the leaf falls.

The given sequence for leaf positions, starting at time 0, is [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4].  Coverage of the river (given as 5 units wide) as time progresses is like this, where `0` denotes a leaf, `-` denotes open water:

```
0   0 - - - -
1   0 - 0 - -
2   0 - 0 - -   There are now 2 leaves in position 1
3   0 - 0 0 -
4   0 0 0 0 -
5   0 0 0 0 -   ... and a second leaf at 3
6   0 0 0 0 0   ... and now, the frog can cross.
```

Answer (score 0):

**RUBY**
I am trying to implement this problem using Ruby with N complexity.. I will run a loop on falling leaves from tree and each time a falling leaf gets new position I will delete that position from the path array which I have created on the basis of steps required.

```
def frogJump(x,arr)         
path_array =(1..x).to_a             
  count = 0           
for position in arr            
  if path_array.size > 0          
  count+= 1               
  path_array.delete(position) if path_array.include?(position)          
  end          
end        
puts count                     
end          

x= 5             
arr = [1 ,2, 3 , 1 , 4 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 4]                  
frogJump(x,arr)
```

Comment: Hi JyotiShukla, it looks like you are trying to ask a question in this answer - it's not clear how this resolves the OP from 2018 (or is adding to it).  Please consider the accepted answer and if you can add to it please update it, OR identify how your answer adds to solving the OP.